# SQLite copy row and change two values in one query

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert

I use SQLite and I need to copy one row and change 2 values preferably in one query.

Now I have a following code:

```
var timestamp = new Date().toString().replace(' GMT+0100 (CET)', '');
            db.run("INSERT INTO scene (name,timestamp,user_id) SELECT name,timestamp,user_id FROM scene WHERE id = ?",req.param('scene'));
            db.run("UPDATE scene SET timestamp=? WHERE id = ?",timestamp, req.param('scene');
```

It works fine, but I would like to update `timestamp` already in first query so I do not have to run another db statement.

Is there any way to to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not test it. But would this work?

```
var timestamp = new Date().toString().replace(' GMT+0100 (CET)', '');
db.run("INSERT INTO scene (name,timestamp,user_id) SELECT name,?,user_id FROM scene WHERE id = ?",timestamp,req.param('scene'));
```

Comment: Thanks - let me check :)